# Jmeter Extracting response body

Tags: jmeter

my web sampler request has a reponse message of

```
[Message 1]
{"event":"pusher:connection_established","data":"{\"socket_id\":\"177828.486549\",\"activity_timeout\":120}"}
```

How I can extract 177828.486549?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually regular expression for this is very simple, you only need to remember that backslash - `\` is a special "escape" character hence it needs to be escaped with another backslash

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the element which returns above message
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything making sense, i.e. `socket_id`
   - Regular Expression: `"socket_id\\":\\"(.+?)\\"`
   - Template: `$1$`
3. Refer extracted value as `${socket_id}` where required

Demo (you can test your regular expressions right in [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

[image: Regular Expression Extractor.]

References:

- [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [USING REGULAR EXPRESSION EXTRACTOR](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)